# How to prove that ${n\choose 0} < {n\choose 1} < \ldots < {n\choose (n+1)/2}$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove that ${n\choose 0} < {n\choose 1} < \ldots < {n\choose (n+1)/2}$ (for every $n$)
I tried to do it with induction but I got stuck.

Comment: Just write the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials and make some cancellations.

Comment: It is not quite true.  For example with $n=3$ you have ${3\choose 0} < {3\choose 1} = {3\choose 2}$

Comment: Henry^ that's why I said until ${n\choose (n+1)/2}$
and I meant <= and not just <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n-k+1}{k}\cdot\binom{n}{k-1}$. Hence, the inequality is true as long as $n-k+1>k$, or rearranging:  $\frac{n+1}{2}>k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By definition ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, where $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge k $. Use this definition assuming the proposition to be true and show that it satisfies the constraints on the definition. Also note that the inequality can go on till ${n\choose \frac{1}{2}(n-1)}$.